# Why does an earlier CSS rule override a later rule?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In my stylesheet, `.four-across li` defines `width: 174px;` at line 8806. Below that rule at line 9603, `.no-search-results` defines `width: auto;`. However, the 174px rule is overriding an element with `.no-search-results`. Why would that be?

[image: CSS in Chrome Developer Tools]

Comment: Order does matter. :)
More info here http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order

Comment: [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Order only matters when multiple selector statements have equal specificity.

Comment: It's because the first css entry is more specific.

Comment: @Sharath: This question demonstrates otherwise. Your point?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should read about CSS specificity.

`.four-across li` is more specific than `.no-search-results`, so it have higher importance level.

> Specificity is calculated by counting various components of your css
>   and expressing them in a form (a,b,c,d). This will be clearer with an
>   example, but first the components.
>
> - Element, Pseudo Element: d = 1 – (0,0,0,1)
> - Class, Pseudo class, Attribute: c = 1 – (0,0,1,0)
> - Id: b = 1 – (0,1,0,0)
> - Inline Style: a = 1 – (1,0,0,0)

by [Understanding Style Precedence in CSS: Specificity, Inheritance, and the Cascade](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/)

Document order matters only when given specificity is exactly the same. In you example first selector is (0,0,1,1) and second is (0,0,1,0), so the first one overrides the second one, no matter how are they ordered within CSS document.

Answer (score 2):

Read:

- [Reviewing CSS Style Priority Level](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-priority-level/)
- [Understanding Style Precedence in CSS: Specificity, Inheritance, and the Cascade](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vanseodesign.com%2Fcss%2Fcss-specificity-inheritance-cascaade%2F&ei=YN8cUonxN-vy7AbA2oGQCg&usg=AFQjCNHPR8IhbiMkL5yGWR1HeAqxOjyloQ&sig2=26sqcnAHFx1dYk9w7pRxUQ&bvm=bv.51156542,d.ZG4)

In this case it's because a *class* and an *element type* are more specific than just a *class*, and it's favored over the *order*.

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons:

1. The last rule scanned has precedence over those scanned previously, all else being equal.
2. The more specific the rule is (two specifiers as opposed to one) the higher the precedence.

Comment: For 2, it's a little more complex than that. Different types of selectors have different scores and the total is used to choose which rule to follow, but the gist of your answer is correct.